# Awk command to replace a substring with a specific value

Tags: awk, gsub

I have a flat file which has phone number in field starting at 314 till 323. Now I wanted to dummy out that field with 1234567890

For this I tried using the below commands but both are throwing errors.

```sh
awk '{var=substr($0,314,10);gsub("[0-9]","1234567890",$var); print}' final_phone.txt >final_phone.txt1
```

```sh
awk 'var=substr($0,314,10) { $var = "1234567890" }1' final_phone.txt >final_phone.txt1
**fatal: grow_fields_arr: fields_arr: can't allocate 9849885432 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)**
```

In the first case I tried to assign the substring to a variable and in `gsub` I wanted to check for numbers pattern and substitute with 1234567890.

In the second case I was trying to assign the value to each of the substring value in each line.

Can someone help me with the syntax here?

Comment: try replacing `$var` with `var`; `awk` ***variable*** references do not require a leading `$`; `awk` does use a leading `$` to reference ***fields*** (in a line); in both examples `$var` says to reference field # `<big-10-digit-number>` ... and I'm *guessing* `awk` is trying to allocate memory structures for `<big-10-digit-number>` fields (eg, allocate memory for `1,234,567,890` fields) hence the 'out-of-memory' error message

Comment: Thanks that worked without the error but the value didnt change                              awk 'var=substr($0,314,10) { var = "1234567890" }1' final_phone.txt >final_phone.txt1

Comment: `var="1234567890"` assigns a value to an in-memory ***variable*** ... this will have no effect on the actual data in the line; one idea that comes to mind: `$0 = substr($0,1,313) "1234567890" substr($0,324)` (so no need for `var` at all?); other `awk`ers may have some better ideas ... perhaps a `(g)(en)sub` call if the phone number you're looking to replace is guaranteed to be unique within the entire line

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on multiple sites (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/674384/133219), especially when you already have an answer the first place you asked the question.

Comment: My bad. I thought both are seperate forum's. Will delete it on one site

Answer (score 0):

[@markp-fuso's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678703/awk-command-to-replace-a-substring-with-a-specific-value#comment123163003_69678703) abut why your code is generating that specific error message is correct.

All you need is:

```
awk '{$0=substr($0,1,313) "1234567890" substr($0,324)} 1' file
```

or if you want to check for numbers first:

```
awk 'substr($0,314,10) ~ /^[0-9]+$/{$0=substr($0,1,313) "1234567890" substr($0,324)} 1' file
```

and using variables:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { beg=314; lgth=10; new="1234567890" }
    substr($0,beg,lgth) ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {
        $0 = substr($0,1,beg-1) new substr($0,beg+lgth)
    }
1' file
```